# Datamatrix/QRCode online resource for encoding?

Tags: barcode

Is there any free online resource explaining how to encode those barcodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page should explain the encoding algorithm:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100830111303/https://www.swetake.com/qr/qr1_en.html

Answer (score 3):

The ZXing project has an [encoder](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder) for QR codes. It's not really an explanation of the QR code spec, since ISO 18004 is for-pay, but might be better than nothing, depending on your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_matrix_%28computer%29#How_it_works):

> Although this is a free standard,
>   there are no free documents that
>   explain the encoding process.
>   Documentation in PDF or paper format
>   can be purchased from the ISO web
>   site.